"ValueError: Shapes are incompatible", but where?
I load my datasets with keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(). Here's the code:
train_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
  "train",
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(224, 224))

val_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
  "test",
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(224, 224))

class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)

print("image and label batch for train, than for val")
for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
  print(image_batch.shape)
  print(labels_batch.shape)
  break
for image_batch, labels_batch in val_ds:
  print(image_batch.shape)
  print(labels_batch.shape)
  break

And here's the output of this part:
Found 75 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 60 files for training.
Found 65 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 13 files for validation.
['corner', 'round']
image and label batch for train, than for val
(32, 224, 224, 3)
(32,)
(13, 224, 224, 3)
(13,)

Then the tutorial had the normalization block:
normalization_layer = Rescaling(1./255)
normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))

Then I create a sequential model, to partly fill it with vgg16 imagenet weights, and then add some more layers for the two classes of mine:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(224,224,3),filters=64, name='block1_conv1',
                 kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
...
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2), name='block5_pool'))

model.load_weights("vgg16_w.h5", skip_mismatch=True, by_name=True)
for i in range(0,9):
    model.layers[i].trainable = False

model.add(Flatten(name='flatten'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu", name="deeper"))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu", name="more_deeper"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="relu", name="to_narrow"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax", name="round_or_sharp"))
print(model.summary())

Then there's compiling:
boardy = TensorBoard(log_dir='./grph')
opt_big = Adam(learning_rate=0.3)
opt_small = SGD(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=opt_big, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds,epochs=48,callbacks=[boardy])

And here's what happens on fit():
Epoch 1/48
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Practice/prjPy/graph_cnn/vgg-dataset.py", line 119, in <module>
    model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds,epochs=48,callbacks=[brdy])
  File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filemtsrptmq.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1338, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1322, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1303, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1081, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1139, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 142, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 268, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 2122, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\Juliy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py", line 5560, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible

The only "2" in my shapes is the one of the output layer, and using
model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax", name="wants_a_one"))
helped to avoid the error message, but there wasn't any classifying.
Epoch 47/48

1/2 [==============>...............] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5938
2/2 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5667 
2/2 [==============================] - 27s 14s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5667 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.6923
Epoch 48/48

1/2 [==============>...............] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5625
2/2 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5667 
2/2 [==============================] - 26s 13s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.5667 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.6923
expected round

1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 364ms/step
[[1.]]

1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 219ms/step
[[1.]]
expected sharp

1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 276ms/step
[[1.]]

1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 239ms/step
[[1.]]

Right now I'm practicing for a bigger range of classes, so making it binary isn't what I need.
How do I fix the ValueError?

changing your loss to sparse_categorical_crossentropy or Binary Cross Entropy should help. categorical_crossentropy needs the labels to be one-hot-encoded. If they are not and just integers you need the sparse version or if it is binary you need the binary one. *Also if your using binary classification swap your activation function to Sigmoid instead of softmax

You have a problem with your training data. You print the shape and it is (32,) it should be (32, 2). You need to look at the data and see why. Is it encoding the values, are they 0, 1? Then you need to encode them correctly.

It turned out that image_dataset_from_directory() needed the labels = "inferred", label_mode = "categorical" part, and no validation_split=0.2, subset="validation" part.

Maybe that should be your answer. Although it seems a bit specific to your situation. I would suggest writing an answer with the new data loading code and include the shapes of the input and output data. It could be useful for somebody.
